# Passing bundle specific config values to WSO2 ESB bundle

Tags: wso2, osgi, properties-file

I want to extend a WSO2 ESB (v 4.7.0) with a custom OSGi bundle providing a service. This bundle is independent of any Mediator, but needs different configuration depending on the current environment (development, test, etc.). So it would be nice to be able to configure these parameters outside of the bundle, e.g. in a properties file.

I found the following link for such a use case for WSO2 Carbon, but this doesn't seem to work in WSO2 ESB: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Config+Files+for+Third+Party+JARs

Is there a way to store the properties in a classpath that will be somehow attached to the bundle at it is described in the link above. Or is it possible to somehow provide the path to the OSGi bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of problems did you face when trying to follow the given doc (fragment bundle approach)? It should work for ESB too since it's based on Carbon.

As an alternative, you can keep the configs in registry
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Working+with+the+Registry

You can upload the config files to the registry through the management console web UI and then inside the bundle you can programmatically access the registry and read the files/configs. (But this may be an overkill for your requirement)

As a workaround, if you are just trying to find the ESB's location to get the path of the config file (which may be in repository/conf), you can construct that path relative to the bundle's location by finding the path of the bundle.

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().toURI()
```

this will give you something like `<esb-location>/repository/components/dropins/YourBundle.jar`, based on that you can construct the path to `<esb-location>/repository/conf/`.

Comment: The fragment bundle approach did never work. I tried different names for the directories (jar name, bundle name, etc.), but the fragment bundle was never created, nor any exception or something like that was shown.